# Splitting the coordinates of the world into equal blocks

Tags: python, algorithm, coordinate-system

It's a function to split the coordinates to some small blocks. For example, some country has a coordinates of north-east and south-west, two diagonals.

If I set the interval to 0.05, it will returns all the coordinates with an interval of 0.05 (or some very close value).

Note: you could regard the blocks as square, and the length of it's edge is 'interval'

For these function, how can simplify it and make it more readable?

Sample results:

```
[{'ne_lng': -53.0, 'sw_lat': 71.97411764705882, 'interval': 0.05, 'sw_lng': -53.04941176470588, 'ne_lat': 72.0}, {'ne_lng': -53.0, 'sw_lat': 71.94823529411764, 'interval': 0.05, 'sw_lng': -53.04941176470588, 'ne_lat': 71.97411764705882}]





Country = {
    'ne_lat' : 89.000000,
    'ne_lng' : 179.000000,
    'sw_lat' : -89.000000,
    'sw_lng' : -179.000000
}

def getCoordinate(Country, interval):
    ne_lng = Country['ne_lng']
    ne_lat = Country['ne_lat']
    sw_lng = Country['sw_lng']
    sw_lat = Country['sw_lat']
    interval = float(interval)
    i = 0
    temp = ne_lng
    lngList = []
    n = int((ne_lng - sw_lng)/interval)+1
    for _ in range(n):
        i += 1
        lngList.append(temp)
        temp -= (ne_lng - sw_lng) / n
    i = 0
    temp = ne_lat
    latList = []
    n = int((ne_lng - sw_lng)/interval)+1
    for _ in range(n):
        i += 1
        latList.append(temp)
        temp -= (ne_lat - sw_lat) / n
    coordinate = []
    for ki, vi in enumerate(lngList):
        for kj, vj in enumerate(latList):
            if ki == n-1 or kj == n-1:
                pass
            else:
                coordinate.append([vi, vj, lngList[ki+1], latList[kj+1]])
    newList = []
    for host in coordinate:
        newDict = {
            'ne_lng': host[0],
            'ne_lat': host[1],
            'sw_lng': host[2],
            'sw_lat': host[3],
            "interval": interval
        }
        # print posts.insert(newDict)
        newList.append(newDict)
    return newList
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are three ways your code could be made more pythonic (which I consider to be more *readable*):

**Use python keyword expansion:**

Python allows the expansion of a dict object when calling a function.  This means we can change:

```
def getCoordinate(Country, interval):
    ne_lng = Country['ne_lng']
    ne_lat = Country['ne_lat']
    sw_lng = Country['sw_lng']
    sw_lat = Country['sw_lat']
```

To this:

```
def get_coordinate(ne_lng, ne_lat, sw_lng, sw_lat, interval):
```

if we call it like:

```
get_coordinate(interval=100, **Country)
```

**Use list comprehension to remove loop boilerplate:**

This:

```
i = 0
temp = ne_lng
lngList = []
n = int((ne_lng - sw_lng)/interval)+1
for _ in range(n):
    i += 1
    lngList.append(temp)
    temp -= (ne_lng - sw_lng) / n
i = 0
temp = ne_lat
latList = []
n = int((ne_lng - sw_lng)/interval)+1
for _ in range(n):
    i += 1
    latList.append(temp)
    temp -= (ne_lat - sw_lat) / n
```

becomes:

```
n = 1 + int((ne_lng - sw_lng) / interval)
lng_list = [
    ne_lng - (ne_lng - sw_lng) * i / n for i in range(n)]

n = 1 + int((ne_lng - sw_lng) / interval)
lat_list = [
    ne_lat - (ne_lat - sw_lat) * i / n for i in range(n)]
```

**Build the output format while iterating:**

This code takes the product of two lists and builds a list of lists of the results.  It then iterates through that list to generate a list of dicts.

```
for ki, vi in enumerate(lngList):
    for kj, vj in enumerate(latList):
        if ki == n-1 or kj == n-1:
            pass
        else:
            coordinate.append([vi, vj, lngList[ki+1], latList[kj+1]])
newList = []
for host in coordinate:
    newDict = {
        'ne_lng': host[0],
        'ne_lat': host[1],
        'sw_lng': host[2],
        'sw_lat': host[3],
        "interval": interval
    }
    # print posts.insert(newDict)
    newList.append(newDict)
return newList
```

But it is easy to build the dict during the first loop, which will elimnate one entire loop. In addition, the result list can be produced with a list comprehension, which gives:

```
return [
    {
        'ne_lng': vi,
        'ne_lat': vj,
        'sw_lng': lng_list[ki + 1],
        'sw_lat': lat_list[kj + 1],
        "interval": interval,
    }
    for ki, vi in enumerate(lng_list[:-1])
    for kj, vj in enumerate(lat_list[:-1])
]
```

**Note:**

I imagine the second line of:

```
n = 1 + int((ne_lng - sw_lng) / interval)
```

is a bug since at that point a lat is going to be calculated.

**Code:**

For completeness here is the entire code I ended up with:

```
def get_coordinate(ne_lng, ne_lat, sw_lng, sw_lat, interval):
    interval = float(interval)

    n = 1 + int((ne_lng - sw_lng) / interval)
    lng_list = [
        ne_lng - (ne_lng - sw_lng) * i / n for i in range(n)]

    n = 1 + int((ne_lng - sw_lng) / interval)
    lat_list = [
        ne_lat - (ne_lat - sw_lat) * i / n for i in range(n)]

    return [
        {
            'ne_lng': vi,
            'ne_lat': vj,
            'sw_lng': lng_list[ki + 1],
            'sw_lat': lat_list[kj + 1],
            "interval": interval,
        }
        for ki, vi in enumerate(lng_list[:-1])
        for kj, vj in enumerate(lat_list[:-1])
    ]


Country = {
    'ne_lat': 89.000000,
    'ne_lng': 179.000000,
    'sw_lat': -89.000000,
    'sw_lng': -179.000000
}

new_data = get_coordinate(interval=100, **Country)
old_data = getCoordinateOrig(Country, 100)
assert new_data == old_data
```